# Is it a good idea to "abscond" if company withholds salary during notice period?

Tags: salary, job-change, india, notice-period

I recently joined a company, and after working for about a month, I have got a better offer. My notice period is 2 months. My company withholds the salary during notice period, and it is paid only 30 days after leaving the company. 
If I resign now and serve the notice period, I will be without salary for 2 months, which I cannot afford.

What are my options to deal with this situation? Should I just "abscond", that is, leave without letting anyone know? Would it impact my career in the long term?

Comment: Does your job include a probationary period? Why do you think you'd be without salary within your notice period?

Comment: No probation period and we normally don't get salary in notice period.

Comment: Could you add the country you are in? This seems very iffy.

Comment: No salary in notice period?  Why would anyone ever hang around for it?

Comment: You don't get *paid* during your notice period? Why the hell would you even *sign* such a contract in the first place?

Comment: Check with a lawyer, this doesn't seem right.

Comment: Don't post misinformation. You join shady companies and then blame "most of the companies in India". Never heard of any reputed companies holding notice period salary. Your company is not most companies.

Comment: Well it's my experience.

Comment: Is notice period without salary even legal in your country? In all countries I know about this, it is illegal.

Comment: That aside, do you actually know that your salary will be withheld during notice period, or are you just speculating based on some rumours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience in the Indian IT industry, I would offer you the following advice: **negotiate the joining date with the new employer, and proceed from there**.

Ask them how soon or how late you can join them. Good companies are flexible to a reasonable extent. Depending on their response, choose one of the options:

1. **You can join immediately or before 2 months**: One day before your joining date at the new job, vanish without a trace from your current job, or as is commonly known in the Indian IT parlance, "abscond". **You will burn a bridge, but some bridges are not worth keeping.** If this company withholds your salary for 3 months, it is not a company where you would want to work in future anyway. Don't make your life miserable for the sake of keeping a bridge.

   **WARNING**: Don't do this <s>again</s> frequently in your career.
2. **You can join only after 2 months**: In this case, you will have to take a blow on the chin, and **serve out the notice period at your current company**. In this case, absconding is a bad idea. If you serve the notice period, you can hope to receive the salary after 3 months, but if you abscond and stay unemployed for 2 months, you can forget about the money.

   Let this also be a lesson in personal finance. **Even though you should avoid feeding off your savings as much as possible, you should also have enough savings to carry you through for at least a year.** What would you have done if you had *lost* your job at this point, with no other offer in hand? By comparison, your situation of company "withholding" your salary, and having another offer sounds a lot better.

In future, before accepting a job offer, do a due diligence on your part, and **avoid working for companies which have a reputation for shady business practices**, like withholding people's salary. The short term gratification of getting *some or the other* job immediately creates lots of problems later, as you are experiencing currently. It is much better to wait for an offer from a more employee-friendly company to come along. While Indian IT companies are not exactly the gold standard for employee-friendliness, very few of them are slave drivers as you seem to believe.

Comment: I agree and I don't plan to do it again. Should I play safe? for example for this job we had to move to a different city and hence I can tell them that my wife is not able to settle down to this environment or my something related to my health. Overall anything better than absconding would be great.

Comment: If you get the feeling that they will accept those reasons and waive off your notice period, then by all means, give it a shot. Notice period negotiations is a lot more about interpersonal skills than company policy. If you can successfully convince them, nothing like it. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged this India, I think your thing with relieving letters will make just quitting without notice period quite hard. Before you do anything, ask your potential new company if they would even employ you without a relieving letter from your former company. The last thing you want to happen is to burn bridges with *both* ending up with *no* job.

> What could be alternatives to get out of this situation?

Assuming the situation is as described (still sounds fishy to me), you do have another option: stay with the job you have. Just "recently" it was good enough and hasn't changed. The grass is always greener on the other side of the fence. Meaning the other offer always looks better. Until you start there. And get another offer from yet another company.

You signed a contract. Keep to it. Learn to deliver what you promised. Save enough money so you can eat the notice period and *then* start looking for the job you want.

In the future, you may want to check more closely what you sign and vote for people that pass better labor laws in your country. No salary in the notice period seems very strange and would probably not hold up in court where I live.

Comment: The current job I have was on need basis it was not my first choice because I am a contractor here. The first job I applied for were not sure about my candidacy they just called me a week back and want me now.

Comment: @vivek Well, when it was convenient for you, you signed the contract. Signing a contract is your *word* you will do it. Just *keeping it* is indeed an option. Matter of fact it's the normal way most of the world operates on.

Comment: So, what should I do now? Looking after my work life balance or being loyal to a company which I joined recently?

Comment: @vivek That's for you to decide. If your work-life-balance is not good, you should not have signed this in the first place. Learn from it and not get into this situation again. Your current contract seemed to be "good enough" just recently and without the offer would still be "good enough" for you now.

Comment: As I told it was not my choice, hope I could have freedom to choose.

Comment: @vivek There is no slavery, not even in India. It *was* your choice. You signed the contract. You could have chosen to wait or to find another job with a probation period or you could have worked at a McJob to pay the bills until the better company decides. Your life is full of choices *you* make and that includes this contract.

Comment: So you are saying that I can quit in probation period? In that case I would need to check offer letter from my employer. Also, can I check if my notice period can be bought?

Comment: @vivek It's common to be able to quit more easily during a probation period where I live. You will need to consult your contract to see what it says.

Comment: That seems good to me infact it's the right thing to do let employee have the option to chose for first couple of months.

Comment: @vivek: It does NOT matter what seems right to you. What matter is what the contract says and what the company policy says. I strongly suggest you read this carefully and don't speculate or ask strangers on the Internet.

Comment: @nvoigt "It was your choice." That's a bold assertion to make if you don't know the OP's financial situation. It sounds like the job they have now _is_ the McJob to pay the bills - but that it came with a fishy clause in the contract.

Comment: @AllTheKingsHorses A contract is *by definition* a choice. A contract signed under threat of force is invalid in any country I know. Not liking a choice you made is no base for breaking a contract. We'd all be outraged if the *employer* broke the contract and said "you know, you were just a McWorker to me, don't come in tomorrow and don't expect payment". The cost for this job was 2 months notice. Taking the job and not paying the cost is simply dishonest.

Comment: @nvoigt I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing here and I can't see the edit history of the question. What I understood is that whenever the OP quits (now or in 10 years), they are expected to work for 2 months and wait for another month before they get the salary for the entire notice period. And that I already find pretty outrageous and  unconscionable. I have no issue with 2 month notice periods, I just expect an employer to deliver money for work in a timely fashion, just as the employer expects work for money.